# no place in which

Tags: grammar

> My father was a year or so older than his brother Oscar, but they were exceptionally close, and soon after they left school, they went for a long walk together to plan their future. They decided that a small town like Sarpsborg in a small country like Norway was **no place in which** to make a fortune. So what they must do, they agreed, was go away to one of the big countries, either to England or France, where opportunities to make good would be boundless

boy by roald dahl

My question : Is it a relative clause and "which" refers to Norway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference is to Sarpsborg  or more exactly to any town **similar** to Sarpsborg.  Let's consider some simpler versions and work up to the given quote.

> (1) Sarpsborg was no place to make a fortune.

That particular town was not suitable for ambitious young men.

> (2) A small town like Sarpsborg was no place to make a fortune.

An similarly small town was not suitable.

> (3) A small town like Sarpsborg in a small country like Norway was no place to make a fortune.

Such a small town was not suitable, **if** it was in such a small country.

> (4) A small town like Sarpsborg in a small country like Norway was no place in which to make a fortune.

Include the previously omitted prepositional phrase of the adjectival dependent clause. The meaning is the same as (3).

So "in which to make a fortune" is an adjectival dependent clause, starting with ***in which***.  Some describe "in which" as a separate relative pronoun, others as the relative pronoun "which" preceded by the preposition "in", together forming a prepositional phrase. In either case, the clause "in which to make a fortune" serves to modify the noun "place".

See

- [Difference Between Which and In Which in English Grammar](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-which-and-in-which-in-english-grammar/)
- ["Identifying Dependent Clauses: Definition, Examples, & Exercises"](https://www.albert.io/blog/dependent-clauses/).
- ["in which vs which"](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/in-which-vs-which)
- ["In which", "of which", "at which", "to which"](https://preply.com/en/question/in-which-of-which-at-which-to-which-41421)
- ["'Where' Versus 'In Which'"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/where-versus-in-which)
- ["Relative Pronouns: Restrictive And Non-Restrictive"](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/relative_pronouns.html)

Comment: To be accurate, the relative pronoun is not "in which" but just "which", the latter being complement of the preposition "in" in the relative clause.

Comment: @Bill at leat one of the sources i linked to said " Both *which* and *in which* are relative pronouns." {italics in original} and no site I found described it as you do. But in any case it is a dependent adjectival clause, I believe.

Comment: @Bill I looked for and cited additional sources, and modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you all so much, but then I have another question. Since 3 and 4 are the same meaning, why bother to use "in which"?

Comment: @wtdark The construction with a _wh_ infinitival is limited to somewhat more formal style, but other than that there's little to choose between the two. Syntactically they are of course slightly different.

Comment: Thank you, got it now.

Comment: I would avoid the term 'adjectival clause' since it implies that the clause is some kind of adjective. It isn't, it's a relative clause functioning as a modifier. We don't want to call every kind of element that can modify a noun 'adjectival'.  Incidentally, the head of the dependent relative clause is not "in which" but "make". The head of a clause is always a verb (or verb phrase).

Comment: @Bill, I believe that it is not a relative clause, because it is neither a defining clause, nor one that provides additional information. It is another form of dependent clause. It modifies a noun, and therefor is "adjectival". Some sources use the term "adjective clause" These describe it much more clearly than "relative clause".  I will remove that use of "head".

Comment: It qualifies as a relative clause because it has a relativised element, "which", anaphorically linked to the head noun "place". In addition to AdjPs, nouns accept a wide range of modifiers such as PPs, VPs, clauses, nominals and even AdvPs.  We don't want to call them all adjectival -- they are modifiers. Note that 'relative' is a clause type, not a part of speech.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *They decided that a small town like Sarpsborg in a small country like*
> *Norway was no place* [*in which to make a fortune*].

Yes, the bracketed element is an infinitival relative clause modifying the nominal "place", which is the antecedent for the relative pronoun "which".

It is also possible to have a non-*wh* infinitival relative clause, as in [2]:

> [2] *They decided that a small town like Sarpsborg in a small country like*
> *Norway was no place* [*to make a fortune*].

The construction in [1] with a *wh* infinitival is limited to somewhat more formal style, but other than that there's little to choose between the two. Syntactically, they are of course slightly different.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I also noticed you mentioned it as "no place" instead of "place". Is it because it is a phrase? I mean, like for this sentence " there's no reason why we shouldn't go back there",   it is "reason/why".

Comment: Strictly speaking, the antecedent is just the nominal "place", not the full NP "no place". I have edited my answer to reflect this.